# In Tensorflow, what is the difference between sampled_softmax_loss and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow, there are methods called [`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) and [`sampled_softmax_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss).

I read the tensorflow document and searched google for more information but I couldn't find the difference. It looks like to me both calculates the loss using softmax function.

#### Using `sampled_softmax_loss` to calculate the loss

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(...))
```

#### Using `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` to calculate the loss

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(P, Q))
```

To me, calculating softmax loss is same as calculating softmaxed cross entropy (e.g. `cross_entropy(softmax(train_x))`)

Could somebody tell me the why there is two different methods and which method should I use in which case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your target vocabulary(or in other words amount of classes you want to predict) is really big, it is very hard to use regular softmax, because you have to calculate probability for every word in dictionary. By Using  `sampled_softmax_loss` you only take in account subset **V** of your vocabulary to calculate your loss.

Sampled softmax only makes sense if we sample(our **V**) less than vocabulary size. If your vocabulary(amount of labels) is small, there is no point using `sampled_softmax_loss`.

You can see implementation details in this paper:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.2007v2.pdf

Also you can see example where it is used - Sequence to sequence translation in this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py)

Comment: Hi Farseer, I kind of struggle with the same issue as above. My output vocabulary is only around 100 labels. Now, tensorflow only provides the sampled_softmax_loss function. Instead of this one, could I use the tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(weights)) + biases) function? Or can I just use the seq2seq_model.py as it is?

Comment: Hi Farseer, is the "sample" step only happens in training phase or happens in both training and predicting phases?

Answer (score 3):

### Sampled:

Sampled, in both cases means you don't calculate it for all of what's possible as an output (e.g.: if there are too many words in a dictionary to take all of them at each derivation, so we take just a few samples and learn on that for NLP problems).

#### `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`:

This is the cross entropy and receives logits as inputs and yields what can be used as a loss.

#### `sampled_softmax_loss`:

This is a sampled softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, so it takes just a few samples before using the cross entropy rather than using the full cross entropy: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1269