# Loss function in tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function, sampled-softmax

I have a question regarding Tensorflow:

Which loss function is used in [`tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss)?

I believe it's ***cross-entropy***, but it is not written on the official website. Can anyone confirm my guess?

Comment: @ibarrond  Yes, it is. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241251/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-sampled-softmax-loss-and-softmax-c), it looks like it is cross entropy.

Besides, the main difference between `sampled_softmax_loss` and `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` (the standard cross_entropy loss in TF) is that the first only takes into account a subset V of your vocabulary to calculate your loss, while the second takes into account your entire vocabulary.